# I tried to return a pointer from a function? But i am not able to get the value back on that specified address

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *changeAddress(){


     int c=23;  
        int *ptr= &c;
        printf("Inside function Address of Pointer is %p\n",ptr);
        printf("Inside function Value of of Pointer is %d\n",*ptr);
        return (ptr);

}
int main(void){


     int *b=changeAddress();
        printf("Inside main Address of Pointer is %p\n",b);
        printf("Inside main Value of of Pointer is %d\n",*b);
        return 0;

}
```

//In the above program i am trying to access the value of local variable c and pass it to the main function and trying to get back the value of c variable in the main function.

Comment: As per the code , the specified return value of c will be 23. seems ok

Comment: @Kiran no, `c` is out of scope and undefined upon return from`changeAddress`.  So the value of `*b` in `main` is undefined.

Comment: @ameyCU Thank you, this works but i don't know about memory allocation in C.

Comment: You can also use `static int c=23;` to fix the problem.

Comment: "*i don't know about memory allocation*" then you either learn it as *next* step, or simply put your hand off C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `int *changeAddress()` you `return` pointer to an local variable -

```
int c=23;           //local variable which is on stack
int *ptr= &c;
```

Address of `c` becomes invalid as soon as your function terminates . ***You can use this variable only inside your function and not out of your function blocks*** . Therefore, you don't get desired output in `main` , as you try to access an invalid memory location (*undefined behaviour*).

You can re-write your program  -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *changeAddress(){
    int c=23;  
    int *ptr= malloc(sizeof(int));           //allocate memory to pointer
    if(ptr==NULL)                            //check if pointer is NULL
            return NULL;
    *ptr=c;
    printf("Inside function Address of Pointer is %p\n",ptr);
    printf("Inside function Value of of Pointer is %d\n",*ptr);
    return (ptr);
  }
int main(void){
    int *b=changeAddress();
    if(b==NULL)                             //check if return is NULL
         return 1;
    printf("Inside main Address of Pointer is %p\n",b);
    printf("Inside main Value of of Pointer is %d\n",*b);
    free(b);                                 //free allocated memeory
    return 0;
}
```